# JSON to OData String for Query

Tags: json, angular, typescript, serialization, odata

How can I turn a JSON object, i.e. `{ username: "john", password: "1234" }` into an OData string query in a function using typescript?  I could not find a library to do this for me (Angular 6).  Here is my attempt:

```
function ConvertToODataString (json: Object) {
    let ret_str: string = "";
    for (let key in json) {
        ret_str += (key + "=" + json[key] + "&");
    }
    if (ret_str) {
        ret_str = ret_str.substr(0, ret_str.length - 1);    // remove last &
    }
    return ret_str;
}
```

Does anyone know of a better way?  For now, my json is not multi-leveled.

Comment: When you say "a JSON object", you start with the object instance or with the JSON string?

Comment: @ConnorsFan JSON object / instance

Comment: I think I probably need something more like `$filter=username eq 'john' and password eq '1234'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to enumerate the object properties, adding each key/value pair to an array, and combine the values with [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
function convertObjectToQuery(obj: Object): string {
  let values = new Array<string>();
  for (let prop in obj) {
    values.push(`${prop} eq '${obj[prop]}'`);
  }
  return encodeURI("$filter=" + values.join(" and "));
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmxjma) for a demo.

Comment: Good idea, although I think my question should probably be worded differently because I am querying for these values, so I need the `$filter` operator and a different syntax.

Comment: I modified the answer and the stackblitz according to your comments. Please edit the question if that is the format that you need.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse function.

Example:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');


json={ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"};
var obj = JSON.parse(json+'');
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` converts a string into an object, the opposite of what I need.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but `JSON.stringify` will not format the string for OData querying.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the [HttpParms](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) module instead:

```
import { HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

const params = new HttpParams()
    .set("$filter", "Username eq '" + parameters["Username"] + "' and Password eq '" + parameters["Password"] + "'")
    .set("$count", "true");

console.log(params.toString());
```